# What are alternatives to NOT IN with a very long list of parameters in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, performance

In a SQL Server database, when I use the `NOT IN` clause with a very long list of values (tens of thousands), the query is turning very slow.

For example:

```
SELECT *
FROM sometable
WHERE id NOT IN (1,2,3,4, ... 99998, 99999)
```

The values for the `NOT IN` clause do not exist in the database itself, so they cannot be used directly, for example in a join or a subquery.

Are there better (especially faster) alternatives?

Answer (score 2):

When the list is long, consider *passing* it into SQL Server using a table-valued parameter. Once it's on the SQL side, it looks like a table variable - so this example uses that:

```
declare @ids table (id int not null primary key)
insert into @ids(id) values (1),(2),(3),(99999)

SELECT st.*
FROM sometable st
      LEFT JOIN
     @IDs i
      ON
         st.ID = i.ID
WHERE i.ID is null
```

We do a `LEFT JOIN` in the `FROM` clause and then filter in the `WHERE` clause to only those result rows where the join failed.

Answer (score 2):

Temporary table, table variable. Whatever - load the values into that (which can have statistics - main problem with IN - and NOT IN is IN with a NOT before, you know).

THen use the accoding SQL (NOT EXISTS) to make sure the value is not in the table you jsut created.

Answer (score 1):

Could you try using a CTE and `NOT EXISTS` instead? Using your existing pseudo-SQL:

```
WITH VTE AS(
    SELECT id
    FROM (VALUES(1),(2),(3),(4),...(99998),(99999)) V(id))
SELECT *
FROM sometable st
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM VTE V
                  WHERE V.id = st.id)
```

Answer (score 1):

SELECT *
FROM sometable st
LEFT JOIN STRING_SPLIT('1,2,3,..999',',') AS ss ON ss.value = st.ID 
WHERE ss.value IS NULL